# Align a widget with respect to another widget with dynamic width

Tags: flutter

I am designing a chat UI. As it is a chat so message body can be any length. Wrapping with a Container to give a nice circular design. below my code of my current design.

```
 Flexible(
        child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                color: AppColors.chatMessageBg),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 100),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                messageBodyView(index, item),
                timeView(item)
              ],
            ))),
```

[image]

What I want is the Time text on the right side.

I tried with Align widget,  then this happened

[image]

What I want to achieve

[image]

I hope you all understand my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to achieve. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope it will be clear now what i want

Comment: Could it be because you have a margin set of 100 `margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 100)`?

Comment: Margin has nothing to do with it. I just the margin fo UI purposes. Like every chat application dose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this with @mulder answer.

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: [
    const SizedBox(width: 16),
    loadCircleImage(
        imageUrl: controller.conversation.value.host.image.url,
        width: 25,
        height: 25),
    const SizedBox(width: 10),
    Flexible(
        child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
              color: AppColors.chatMessageBg),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 100),
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                child: messageBodyView(index, item),
              ),
              Opacity(
                opacity: 0,
                child: timeView(item),),

              Positioned(
                  child: timeView(item), bottom: 0, right: 0)
            ],
          )),
    ))
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a stack instead of a column, a row with min size and very important to remove the align from the time field, instead, wrap it with positioned with bottom and right both set to 0.  Also, use an align for your container, instead of the margins to push it to the left (or the right).

Here's the code:

```
Flexible(
                    child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          color: Colors.amber),
                      //margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 100),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 16, right: 16, top: 8, bottom: 8),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Stack(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 18.0),
                                child: messageBodyView(index, item),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                  child: timeView(item), bottom: 0, right: 0)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                ))
```

Comment: It works to some extent. Had to make some changes.

Comment: How about posting the changes you had to make here so that someone can find the right information in future?

Comment: Already done that...

Answer (score 1):

Use constraints in Container.

```
Flexible(
   child: Container(
     constraints:BoxConstraints( 
       maxWidth:200,
      ),
     decoration: const BoxDecoration(                  
       borderRadius: 
        BorderRadius.all( 
        Radius.circular(20)),
       color:AppColors.chatMessageBg),
       margin: const 
        EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right:     
         100),
       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 16, right: 16, 
                top: 8, bottom: 8),
       child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment:   
             CrossAxisAlignment.start,
       children: [
          Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: 
          MainAxisAlignment.start, 
         children: 
          [messageBodyView(index, item),]),
          Row(
         mainAxisAlignment:  
          MainAxisAlignment.end, 
         children: [ timeView(item)]),
              ],
            ))),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is okay. Now what you need is just give a minimum width to the container. So that it looks good when text size is small.

I hope this will resolve the problem. If not can ping me.

Happy Coding

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).